# LXD proxy for DNS

Tags: lxc, lxd, port-forwarding, container

I set up a bind server in a LXD instance and I try to forward all DNS queries from host to this instance. I tried this:

```
sudo lxc config device add bind dnsdevicetcp proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:53 connect=tcp:bind:53
```

but DNS is mainly a UDP service, when I try something like this:

```
sudo lxc config device add bind dnsdeviceudp proxy listen=udp:0.0.0.0:53 connect=udp:bind:53
```

I'll get an error:

```
Error: Proxy device doesn't support the connection type: udp
```

How can I forward queries correctly?

---

Host: Ubuntu Server 18.04

No Virtualization

LXC/LXD version: 3.0.3

Comment: Please advise the distro you installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version. Also please note if you are using virtualizaing, and if so, which virtual engine is used. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using LXD 3.0.x, which does not support *UDP proxy devices*. Support for such proxy devices has been added at a later version (I think LXD 3.4).

Therefore, I suggest to upgrade to the snap package of LXD, by performing the following:

```
sudo snap install lxd
sudo lxd.migrate
```

By doing so, you will get LXD 3.23 (currently the latest version), and it supports UDP proxy devices.

Note that without a LXD proxy device you can still forward network traffic, using `iptables`. However, it is a more involved process because you need to setup the command correctly, and then make it run automatically on your system on each reboot.